# monaco-editor controlled component

Tags: monaco-editor

This question is concerning [monaco-react](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react) library

when i input something like 'hello world'

now:

[image]

but i want:

[image]

I want to intercept input absolutely, because some reason, readOnly is useless

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
<MonacoEditor
  theme="vs-light"
  width={width}
  height={height}
  language={language}
  value={value}
  onMount={handleMount}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
const handleChange = (newValue) => {
  // no changed
  console.log(value);
  // has changed
  console.log(newValue);
  // the editor has changed like the first picture
}
```

How can I control the editor?